# Passing aria-role to Material UI <Icon> component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, wai-aria

I'm currently using Material UI's `<Icon />` component. Material UI's documentation mentions the ability to pass `role="img"` in this article: https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#semantic-svg-icons however I think it only applies to `<SvgIcon />`. Has anyone had any luck passing these props down to the `<Icon />` component?

Here is my sample code that I'm using.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from '@material-ui/core';

export interface IconProps {
  icon: string;
}

export const SampleIcon = ({icon = 'home'}: IconProps) => {
  return (
    <Icon
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Sample Icon"
      component="span"
      role="img"
      title="Sample Icon">
        {icon}
    </Icon>
  );
});
```

Comment: FYI, you can make `icon` optional on `IconProps`.  Otherwise there is no point in setting a default.

Comment: This was brought over from my demo app which allows users to add their own icon which is why I had a default. Everywhere else in my app there isn't a default and it is required.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code that you have.  `Icon` accepts all of the standard JSX attributes which are assignable to any DOM element, including `role`.

Your code outputs the following HTML:

> `<span class="material-icons MuiIcon-root" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Sample Icon" role="img" title="Sample Icon">star</span>`

Comment: Weird, I'll take another look and accept if it works